# After using external HDD in Windows 7, it stopped to be readable in Windows XP

Tags: windows-7, windows-xp, installation, external-hard-drive, data-recovery

After using an external hard drive with Windows 7 (Prof), it stopped to be recognized in any Windows XP (Prof), telling (in XP that it is not formatted and should be formatted for using), though it is usable (the data is readable and writable) in any Windows 7.

What's happened and how to make it again usable in Windows XP?

**Update:**

When it is plugged in Windows XP, the light is on, the HDD is spinning
and I am informed that:
"O:\ is not accessible.

The file directory is corrupt and unreadable"

[image]

Just searched internet for its description.
Since I've bought it 6 years ago 
It corresponds, by the image to [Maxtor Basics Portable 250GB USB2.0 2.5inch External Hard drive - STM902503EHD301](http://www.overclock.co.uk/product/Maxtor-Basics-Portable-250GB-USB20-25inch-External-Hard-drive_9099.html)

I have run more than once chkdisk on it from Windows 7.

[image]

[image]

There are a lot of threads about it "stopped responding" on the internet without any solution

**Update2**

Driverwhiz and DriverPack Soltion 13 show that there are no uninstalled drivers.

Segate DicWizard proposes to delete all pertitions (which is not new as it is proposed by Windows XP though Windows 7 reads OK), though detects it as ST9160821AS 150GB

[image]

Checked in Windows 7 that it is formatted as NTFS and BitLocker is turned off

Comment: What filesystem are you using? Also are you using any disk protection or Bitlocker features?

Comment: Odd, why is there a page file on that external harddrive?

Comment: @surfasb , there is no page file on external drive. It is mapped to letter O:\ (Disk 3)

Comment: @Hari , I've checked from Windows 7 that the filesystem in external drive is NTFS and BitLocker is turned off on it

Comment: Check your drive for bad sectors.

Comment: Also in some drives there is some security features, When I insert my WDC, it shows as a CD drive. I have to run program inside the CD which ask for password. then only I can access my disk. Since it is a windows application I can't use in linux. May be your disk driver might not support in XP